# How to change class labels of a custom Keras data generator

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

I prepared a custom custom image data generator for my Keras application. It works well but I have a problem with the class labels. Here is the related part of the code:

```
    def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):
    # create array to hold the images
    batch_x = np.zeros((4*len(index_array),) + self.target_size+(3,), dtype='float32')
    # create array to hold the labels
    batch_y = np.zeros(4*len(index_array), dtype='float32')
    target_angles = [0, 90, 180, 270]

    for i, j in enumerate(index_array):           
        is_color = int(self.color_mode == 'rgb')
        image = cv2.imread(self.filenames[j], is_color)
        if is_color:
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)                               
        for rotation_angle in target_angles:
            rotated_im = rotate(image, rotation_angle, self.target_size[:2])
            if self.preprocess_func: rotated_im = self.preprocess_func(rotated_im)                  
            batch_x[i] = rotated_im
            batch_y[i] = rotation_angle

    batch_y = to_categorical(batch_y, 271)            
    return batch_x, batch_y
```

As seen in the code I have to use 271 in `to_categorical` method. However I only generate 4 classes. So, how can I assign 0,1,2,3 to 0,90,180 and 270 and use 4 instead of 271 in `to_categorical` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two lists:

```
target_angles = [0,90,180,270]
target_cat_angles = np.array(to_categorical([0,1,2,3]))
```

In the loop:

```
for rotation_angle, cat_angle in zip(target_angles, target_cat_angles):
    ...
    batch_y[i] = cat_angle
    ...
```